# What is the difference between the error handler in condition-case and the error function

Tags: error-handling

I am wondering the semantic of the `error` function. For `condition-case`, the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html) says:

> The arguments after the protected form are handlers. Each handler
>   lists one or more condition names (which are symbols) to specify which
>   errors it will handle.

From its example:

```
(condition-case nil
    (delete-file filename)
  (error nil))
```

The `error` in `(error nil)` is the condition which is a symbol in my understanding.

On the other hand, when we want to raise an error, we use the function `error` as well. From the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signaling-Errors.html#Signaling-Errors):

> Function: error format-string &rest args
>
> This function signals an error with an error message constructed by applying format-message (see Formatting Strings) to format-string and args.

and example:

```
(error "That is an error -- try something else")
```

The error function will create a message and signal the error. What I cannot understand is, what is the difference between this error signaling function, and the error symbol in the `(condition-case)` above? If `(error)` is a function used to signal an error, in the `(condition-case)` above the `(error nil)` should be eval-ed and raise an error with a nil message instead of catching an error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docstring for `condition-case` (`C-h f condition-case`) says:

> condition-case is a special form in `C source code'.
>
> (condition-case VAR BODYFORM &rest HANDLERS)
>
> Regain control when an error is signaled.
>   Executes BODYFORM and returns its value if no error happens.
>   Each element of HANDLERS looks like (CONDITION-NAME BODY...)
>   where the BODY is made of Lisp expressions.

The elisp [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Forms.html#Special-Forms) describes "special form" as (emphasis mine):

> A “special form” is a primitive function specially marked so that its
>   arguments **are not all evaluated**.  Most special forms define control
>   structures or perform variable bindings—things which functions cannot
>   do.
>
> Each special form **has its own rules for which arguments are evaluated
>   and which are used without evaluation**.  Whether a particular argument is
>   evaluated may depend on the results of evaluating other arguments.

So in this case, the *condition name* `error` is not evaluated but simply used as a symbol; if it matches the raised error, the corresponding *body* is evaluated.

Contrary to many programming languages, a symbol is just that, a symbol, although it very often references another object, such as a variable or function.
You may want to have a look at the section on [symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbols.html#Symbols) in the elisp manual to further clarify this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should pay attention to the "special form".